# Python 2to3 windows CMD

Tags: python

I have installed python 32 package to the

> C:\python32

I have also set the paths:

> PYTHONPATH | C:\Python32\Lib;C:\Python32\DLLs;C:\Python32\Lib\lib-tk;
>
> PATH ;C:\Python32;

I would like to use the "2to3" tool, but CMD does not recognize it.

```
CMD: c:\test\python> 2to3 test.py
```

Should i add an extra path for "2to3" or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

2to3 is actually a Python script found in the Tools/scripts folder of your Python install.

So you should run it like this:

```
python.exe C:\Python32\Tools\scripts\2to3.py your-script-here.py
```

See this for more details: http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html

Comment: Use the -w option to not only check what should change, but also write converted code: `python.exe C:\Python32\Tools\scripts\2to3.py -w your-script-here.py`

Comment: By adding `C:\Python32\Tools\scripts\` (adjusted to your Python installation of course) to your `PATH`, you can avoid typing the whole path everytime and just use `2to3.py -w your-script-here.py` from any directory.

Comment: Are you sure about that? By default Windows only recognizes .exe, .com, .bat files, I think for what you're saying you'd have to adjust PATHEXT as well, to include .PY in it.

Comment: For what @CGFoX was suggesting, you can see monknomo's answer below as a working alternative

Answer (score 10):

You can set up 2to3.py to run as a command when you type 2to3 by creating a batch file in the same directory as your python.exe file (assuming that directory is already on your windows path - it doesn't have to be this directory it just is a convenient, relatively logical spot).

Lets assume you have python installed in `C:\Python33`.  If you aren't sure where your python installation is, you can find out where Windows thinks it is by typing `where python` from the command line.

You should have `python.exe` in `C:\Python33` and `2to3.py` in `C:\Python33\Tools\Scripts`.

Create a batch file called `2to3.bat` in `C:\Python33\Scripts` and put this line in the batch file

```
@python "%~dp0\..\Tools\Scripts\2to3.py" %*
```

The `%~dp0` is the location of the batch file, in this case `c:\Python33\Scripts` and the `%*` passes all arguments from the command line to the `2to3.py` script.  After you've saved the .bat file, you should be able to type `2to3` from the command line and see

```
At least one file or directory argument required.
Use --help to show usage.
```

I have found this technique useful when installing from setup.py, because sometimes the setup script expects 2to3 to be available as a command.

Comment: Great answer! That's approximately the same thing I've come up to myself. I'd only suggest adding @ to the .bat file line to suppress output and moving the file to C:\Python35\Scripts dir, as it is a better fit for files like that (for example pip.exe and easy_install are located there).

Comment: Those are all excellent refinements.  I'll edit to reflect your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Make a batch file then rename it to `2to3.bat` and paste this code in it:

```
@python "%~dp0\Tools\Scripts\2to3.py" %*
```

Copy that file beside your python.exe file, for me that folder is:
`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`

Usage:

```
2to3 mycode.py
```