# build boost python 3.4 64 bit

Tags: boost, 64-bit, python-3.4

I am trying to follow the tutorial in Boost.python.

My environment is in the title.

When I try the bjam I receive the following error:

> C:\local\boost_1_57_0\libs\python\example\tutorial>bjam.exe
>   address-model=64 ...patience... ...patience... ...found 1894
>   targets... ...updating 6 targets... msvc.link.dll
>   bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd
>
> Creating library
>   bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_e xt.pdb
>   and object
>   bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext .exp
>   LINK : fatal error LNK1207: incompatible PDB format in
>   'C:\local\boost_1_57_0\li
>   bs\python\example\tutorial\bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\
>   hello_ext.pdb'; delete and rebuild
>
> ```
>     call "C:\Users\Navid\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_12.0_vcvarsall_x86_amd64
> ```
>
> .cmd" >nul link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /NOENTRY /DEBUG
>   /MACHINE:X64 /MANIFEST /subsys tem:console
>   /out:"bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext
>   .pyd"
>   /IMPLIB:"bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pd
>   b" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python34\libs"
>   @"bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threadin
>   g-multi\hello_ext.pyd.rsp"
>           if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%
>
> ...failed msvc.link.dll
>   bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hel lo_ext.pyd
>   bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb bi
>   n\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb...
>   ...removing
>   bin\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb
>   ...skipped hello_ext.pyd for lack of
>   hello_ext.pyd... copy
>   bin\hello.test\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello.py
>   hello.py
>           1 file(s) copied. 2to3 bin\hello.test\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello.py
>   '2to3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. '2to3' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> ```
> 2to3 -wn --no-diffs "bin\hello.test\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threadi
> ```
>
> ng-multi\hello.py"
>       2to3 -dwn --no-diffs "bin\hello.test\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\thread
>   ing-multi\hello.py"
>
> ...failed 2to3
>   bin\hello.test\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\h
>   ello.py... ...removing
>   bin\hello.test\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hell
>   o.py ...skipped
>   hel
>   lo for lack of
>
> > hello.py... ...failed updating 3 targets... ...skipped 3 targets...

I made sure .\b2 adress-model=64 and \turorial>bjam address-model=64

The user-config is also configurd for

> ---
>
> ### MSVC configuration.
>
> using msvc : 12.0 ;
>
> ---
>
> ### Python configuration.
>
> Configure specific Python version. using python : 3.4 : C:\python34 : C:\Python34\include : C:\Python34\libs ;

Answer (score -1):

I want to talk about how to correct the  '2to3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. It means that 2to3 is not in your path.
In order to add it to your path, follow [Python 2to3 windows CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104805/python-2to3-windows-cmd). Follow the last but one answer